# Matrix Playa MSM limit playa children to once per loop

Tags: matrix, playa, multi-site-manager, loop

#### I am running

- EE 2.5.2
- Playa 4.3.3
- Matrix 2.4.3

I have a matrix field inside channel entries pair tag. The first column in that matrix is a playa field type. That playa field relates to a matrix on another site that is run by MSM.

This is all generating a table in my template.

#### what i have so far

I have successfully pulled the playa children using the following:

`{matrix_field}
<tr>
   {if plhotel} <!--playa column-->
    <td>
      {exp:playa:children site="mysite" field="hotels" limit="1"} 
        {hotel-name} <!--desired playa value-->
      {/exp:playa:children}
    </td>
   {/if}
    <td>{other matrix value}</td>
    <td>{other matrix value}</td>
</tr>
{/matrix_field}`

#### my issue

I need for the playa tag to pull one child per row. 
This is almost certainly an issue with how I've constructed the loop, I'm openly admitting this. I can't seem to prevent the playa loop from displaying all children in the first row. As you'll see I've even tried setting limit="1" in the tag which I almost knew would fail. This produced the same child in all rows of the table (still not correct).

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will create any parse issues, but here's a restructure for you:

```
{matrix_field}
{if plhotel} <!--playa column-->
{exp:playa:children site="mysite" field="hotels"}     
<tr>
    <td>
        {hotel-name} <!--desired playa value-->
    </td>
    <td>
        {other matrix value}
    </td>
    <td>
        {other matrix value}
    </td>
</tr>
{/exp:playa:children}
{/if}

{!-- and if you still need to output something even if not plhotel, just use an if:else and repeat your structure --}

{/matrix_field}
```

I don't have a particular playa/matrix set up in mind I can test the possible parse issues in, so give it a whirl.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I move the `{exp:playa…}` tags just out to just inside of the matrix field tags, it renders nothing. I had tried this once before but ran it again just so I could accurately describe the outcome. So it not only doesn't display it's children it also doesn't display any of the successive matrix tag content… I guess that would be considered a parse issue. (still new to EE) I've also tried a few more variations of your suggestion but pushing the playa tags out seems to always result in disrupting any following matrix info.